# Given an integer array nums, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.class

Tags: python, arrays

class Solution:

```
def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
    """
    Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
    """
    temp=[]
    l=len(nums)
    for i in range(l):
        temp[(i+k)%l]=nums[i]
    nums=temp
```

It is giving an error of

> list assignment out of range.

What's the problem?

Comment: Tag the language, also check my edit of your formatting still matches your intention.

Comment: What does the `dsa` tag have to do with this? Please read the description of tags you add.

Answer (score 0):

In Python lists don't grow automatically, so when you do `temp[(i+k)%l]=nums[i]` you will get this error -- the `temp` list is empty, so you cannot assign to any index. To make this work you should either call `temp.append`, or first make sure `temp` has all the entries before starting the loop.

However, the comment at the top of your function clearly indicates that you should perform the rotation in place, and your code is not doing that:

The last statement is **not** mutating the given list. Instead it changes the **local** name to reference another list, but the caller will still see the original list where no rotation happened.

To mutate the original list, assign to `nums[:]`

So -- without changing anything else -- your code can be corrected to this:

```
        temp=[0] * len(nums)  # define all indices
        l = len(nums)
        for i in range(l):
            temp[(i+k)%l] = nums[i]
        nums[:] = temp  # mutate nums
```

#### Improvements

This works, but then why not *first* copy `nums` to `temp`, and then get values *from* `temp` storing them in the rotated position in `nums`. This will need one step less:

```
        temp = nums[:]
        l = len(nums)
        for i in range(l):
            nums[(i+k)%l] = temp[i]
```

You can solve this without writing a loop explicitly and without needing a name to store the rotated result:

```
        k %= len(nums)
        nums[:] = nums[-k:] + nums[:-k]
```

To really do this without O(n) auxiliary memory you could use the 3 x reversal technique:

```
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
        # helper function 
        def reverse_slice(nums, start, end):
            mid = (start + end) // 2
            for i, j in zip(range(start, mid), range(end - 1, mid - 1, -1)):
                nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]

        n = len(nums)
        k = (n - (k % n)) % n  # Express the given rotation in the opposite direction
        reverse_slice(nums, 0, k)
        reverse_slice(nums, k, n)
        nums.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Test case: arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], k = 1

const reverseArray = (arr, start, end) => {
  //swapping two numbers using array destructuring
  while (start < end) {
    [arr[start], arr[end]] = [arr[end], arr[start]]
    start++
    end--
  }
}

const rotate = (arr, k) => {
  // Assuming k = 0, no rotation happens.
  // if arr is empty then no rotation is possible.
  // if the array has one element then no need to rotate.

  //step 1: reverse complete(0 to arr.length - 1) array, time complexity  0(n)
  //step 2: reverse 0 to k-1 
  //step 3: reverse k to arr.length - 1
 
  k = k % arr.length
  reverseArray(arr, 0, arr.length - 1) //[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  reverseArray(arr, 0, k - 1) //[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  reverseArray(arr, k, arr.length - 1) //[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]

  return arr
}
```